# Warning: exec(): Unable to fork in PHP

Tags: php, windows, cmd

I'm using php 5 apache on windows server 2008, I have disabled IIS.

I m using exec command in my PHP script and it was working fine
but today I got an error:

```
Warning: exec(): Unable to fork
```

I gave permissions to `cmd.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32` folder
but this did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 64-bit windows (e.g server 2008), theres a folder named c:\windows\syswow64, that contains all executables/dll, that are required by a 32 bit app. installed on your 64-bit machine.
Make sure your required 32-bit .exe/dll etc is placed in that folder. 
if you cant find it there you will have to put a 32-bit version of the required .exe/dll
there.So this can used by yopur app/process.

Now when your 32-bit application/process executes, windows will automatically redirect your process to execute required app in syswow64 folder.

Hopefully that should resolve your compatibility issue.

Answer (score 4):

Specifically which permissions did you give to who?
Probably not to the right user..

Run this php script:

```
echo 'Script is executed by: ' . get_current_user() . getmygid();
```

It will tell you which user is running the PHP scripts and therefore which user to grant permissions to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. script is executed by SYSTEM and id is 0 and SYSTEM has full control rights

Comment: Try giving permissions to Internet Guest User (IUSR)

Comment: i have IUSR, IIS_IUSRS ,USERS GUESTS and i have given the full control rights, i don't have Internet Guest User. i m using win 2008

Comment: One more thing i m using apache not IIS. i had disabled the IIS

Comment: any more help in this regard?

Comment: Try copying cmd.exe into the folder that contains php.exe
Also try looking at the advanced permissions of cmd.exe, IUSR defaults to DENY - and it might be hidden away.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried ur suggestion by copying cmd.exe in php folder where php.exe located. i already gave full control to IUSR

Comment: try running the script via php (open a cmd terminal, drag the php.exe into the terminal, press space, drag the script into the terminal, press enter) - if it runs then it's permissions or antivirus or something similar, if it doesn't, it's something to do with php or the script you're running

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem myself, but was eventually able to resolve it. The problem was due to how I  had accidentally set cmd.exe to "Run as Administrator" by default. I say "accidentally" as I thought I was only setting the compatibility settings of a shortcut on my task bar, but it turned-out it was setting the compatibility of the .exe itself. Anyhow, I disabled this by deleting the registry key here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

After doing this, everything started working again.